# Perceptual hashing using Insight library

Tags: c++, dll, hash

For a project I am working on I would like to make use of the Insight perceptual hash library. After reading an interesting blog post about it (http://bertolami.com/index.php?engine=blog&content=posts&detail=perceptual-hashing) I have tried to make it work for myself, but I have very little experience working with image files in C++.

The code I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "vnInsight.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CVImage ** A, ** B; // Declare image objects
    UINT32 statusA = vnCreateImage(VN_IMAGE_FORMAT_R8G8B8, 960, 960, A); // Does not actually initialise A?
    UINT32 statusB = vnCreateImage(VN_IMAGE_FORMAT_R8G8B8, 960, 960, B);
    UINT8 * addressA = (*A)->QueryData(); // Documentation says I have to retrieve an address with this function
    vnCompareImages(** A, ** B); // 'A not initialised error'
    return 0;
}
```

The mess above was conjured up by following the documentation with the library, which is small enough that I can copy/paste it here:

> The primary interface to Insight is the CompareImages function:
>
> FLOAT32 vnCompareImages( CONST CVImage & pA, CONST CVImage & pB );
>   This function will return a value in the interval of [0,1] that
>   indicates the percentage of similarity between the two input images.
>
> CVImage objects are simple wrappers around a formatted memory buffer.
>   To create a new image, call vnCreateImage(), passing in the dimensions
>   and desired image format (currently only VN_IMAGE_FORMAT_R8G8B8 is
>   supported by Insight).
>
> Once this call completes, the image object is allocated and ready to
>   be filled with your image data. You can supply this data by copying it
>   to the address indicated by CVImage::QueryData(). Don't forget to call
>   vnDestroyImage() when you've finished with your image object.

My question is; how can I do a simple image similarity check? Moreover, what is a CVImage object exactly? ("simple wrappers around a formatted memory buffer" is not entirely clear to me)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Insight for a university project and had pretty decent results. Your code is close, but needs to be fixed in a few areas:

```
CVImage *A, *B; // Declare image object pointers
vnCreateImage(VN_IMAGE_FORMAT_R8G8B8, 960, 960, &A); // allocate space for image A
vnCreateImage(VN_IMAGE_FORMAT_R8G8B8, 960, 960, &B); // allocate space for image B
```

At this point, A and B each point to allocated but uninitialized images.

Next you need to populate A and B with valid image data (otherwise you will simply be comparing two black images). In my project I loaded the data from bitmap files and copied it into the images.

Once you've properly filled out the images, call vnCompareImages to get the result.

```
FLOAT32 fPercentageMatch = vnCompareImages(*A, *B);
```

Don't forget to deallocate the images once you're finished with them:

```
vnDestroyImage(A);
vnDestroyImage(B);
```